# Delphi - Oracle RowID ignored with dbGO/ADO

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

Delphi Rio - I have dbGO/ADO configured with Oracle (using Oracle's connector, not Microsoft's).    I am working with a simple query.

```
mySQL := 'select REGISTRY_ID, TERRITORY_ID, ACCOUNT_NAME from ACCOUNTS_SI';

ADO_Q1.Close;
ADO_Q1.SQL.Clear;
ADO_Q1.SQL.Add(mySQL);
ADO_Q1.Open;

ShowMessage(IntToStr(ADO_Q1.FieldList.Count));
```

This works exactly as expected, and the Message popup shows 3.  If I add the ROWID as a column, it appears to be totally ignored.  The query below runs, but still shows 3 columns.

```
mySQL := 'select ROWID, REGISTRY_ID, TERRITORY_ID, ACCOUNT_NAME from ACCOUNTS_SI';
```

I have even tried renaming it.

```
mySQL := 'select ROWID as MYKEY_ID, REGISTRY_ID, TERRITORY_ID, ACCOUNT_NAME from ACCOUNTS_SI';
```

ROWID as a column, while completely legal, is being filtered out.

When I look at Oracle's documentation, it seems to show that RowID is perfectly valid.

> In order for the OleDbDataAdapter.Update() method to properly update
> Oracle with changes made in the DataTable, the DataTable must contain
> a primary key of a database table. If the database table does not
> contain a primary key, the ROWID must be selected explicitly when
> populating the DataTable, so that the ROWID can be used to uniquely
> identify a row when updating a row in the database.

Is there a way around this?  How can I use RowID with dbGo? (Yes, I am ware of issues using RowID...but this is a single user, local DB.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it uses ROWID for internal purposes like cursor navigating, so try to add 2 ROWID columns and wrap one in the nested subquery:

```
mySQL := 'select RID, REGISTRY_ID, TERRITORY_ID, ACCOUNT_NAME from (select ROWID, ROWID as RID, s.* from ACCOUNTS_SI s';
```

**Update** (since previous one didn't help)
Another variant:

```
mySQL := 'select RowIDtoChar(ROWID) RID, REGISTRY_ID, TERRITORY_ID, ACCOUNT_NAME from ACCOUNTS_SI';
```

Comment: Good attempt, but unfortunately it did not help....

Comment: @user1009073 ok, please try with to_char from the updated answer

Comment: Still no go... Delphi throws an Oracle Error.  ORA-00932: Inconsistent datatypes:  expected NUMBER got ROWID.  I tweaked the SQL to this...  select RowIDtoChar(ROWID) RID, REGISTRY_ID, TERRITORY_ID, ACCOUNT_NAME from ACCOUNTS_SI  and it works.  Update answer and I will accept.

Comment: @user1009073 thanks, done (forgot about that function)